# How does one show the equivalence principle is manifest in the EH action?

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, action, equivalence-principle

How does one start from the Einstein Hilbert action and show that in a small neighborhood the metric must be Lorentzian (equivalence principle)?

Comment: You mean you want to show Normal coordinates always exist? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates

Comment: @Guliano yes that would suffice

Comment: I believe this is a general mathematical result applicable to any (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold, so the action has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Ah i wasn't aware. Feel free to share an answer (explicitly stating the broadness)

Comment: I think this reference only uses Riemannian manfiolds: http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/16S-RiemGeom/Notes/Lec14.pdf, but according to the wiki there should also be a proof for pseudo-Riemannian ones.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/647687/2451

Comment: Note that not all gravity theories need to respect equivalence principle, like the Brans-Dicke action violates strong equivalence principle